# Why are IE and Firefox returning different overflow dimensions for a div?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox, dom

I have a `div` with a fixed size of 100px. `scrollWidth` and `scrollHeight` works fine if the text in the `div` is normal (no word is long enough to fill the one row entirely). However, if there is any text with one word rendering wider than the 100px it will cause a problem.

Let's say the text is like "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890": then Firefox returns the wrong `scrollWidth` (100 in this case, which is same as the actual width even though the `div` is overflowing). However, IE is giving the correct `scrollWidth` (180 in this case).

Please help me get the correct `scrollWidth` in Firefox. Sorry if my question looks vague.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that your `div` has the `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto` style set. If it's `overflow:visible` (the default), then FF won't calculate a larger `scrollWidth` as *there's nothing to scroll* (the text is all rendered).

The behavior you observed with IE is actually due to [a bug in that browser's implementation](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html#link2) of `overflow:visible`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and feel that this is a bug in Firefox not IE, as per w3 scrollwidth of an element is (padding-right + padding-left + content width) including the overflow. The following fiddle gives the correct value in IE 8 and Chrome but in Firefox it doesn't

http://jsfiddle.net/vdua/Fungh/16/